# create_date < NOW from 1 to 40 second

Tags: php, mysql

How can I use `create_date()` and check the value it returns is less than `NOW`?

The code I am using should test if the returned value is between now and 1 to 40 seconds earlier.

```
            $test= mysql_query("select * FROM ".$database_server.".chat where create_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND and < NOW() - INTERVAL 40 SECOND order by id desc limit 15");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Do you want to select all rows with create_date _between_ 1 and 40 seconds ago?

Comment: @brain99 from 1 second to 40seconds

Comment: Try using `BETWEEN` with the ends of the time range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all rows with created_date between 1 and 40 seconds ago you can use either two conditions or make use of the BETWEEN ... AND operator.

```
$test= mysql_query("select * FROM ".$database_server.".chat where create_date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND) and create_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 SECOND) order by id desc limit 15");

$test= mysql_query("select * FROM ".$database_server.".chat where create_date between (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND) and (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 SECOND) order by id desc limit 15");
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you can of course also just select all rows created less than 40 seconds ago.

```
$test= mysql_query("select * FROM ".$database_server.".chat where create_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 40 SECOND) order by id desc limit 15");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bro:

```
select * from your_table where create_date >= now() - interval 40 second
```